# GIT FTP returning 552 error code but there is plenty of storage

Tags: ftp, git-ftp

I have the following bitbucket YML file which is currently giving me a 552 FTP error code:

```
image: bitnami/git
​
pipelines:
  branches:  # Pipelines that run automatically on a commit to a branch can also be triggered manually
    live:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp push -u $FTP_USERNAME_LIVE -p $FTP_PASSWORD_LIVE $FTP_URL_LIVE
    dev:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp push -u $FTP_USERNAME -p $FTP_PASSWORD -v $FTP_URL
```

Please ignore the live branch as we haven't updated this yet.  it's the dev branch i'm having issues with right now.

I've tried changing the FTP details, checking the storage available on the CPanel account etc and it still wont work and is giving this error.  The FTP account is set to unlimited too.  Does anyone have any suggestions how to get around this?

Comment: git-ftp is an add-on, not part of Git itself. Looks like it's fairly popular; see https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp for links to advice, open issues, and so on.

Comment: Hi @torek this isn't a useful reply, i know that it's not part of Git, i'm not asking if it is, i'm asking for help with my issue, i know where to get help from but my issue isn't being answered there - hence me asking here. Thanks :)

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer: the link goes to points where you might find help, maybe.